# jQuery turn string into span multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to separate the `.string` into `span` elements for every `.item` but cannot find the proper way to do it.

I tried the function below but cannot get it working so that it only works on the closest `.item`.

```
$(".string").html(
  $(".string")
    .html()
    .split(" ")
    .map(function(el) {
      return "<span>" + el + "</span>";
    })
);
```

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  var arr = $(".string").text().split(" ");
  var html = "";
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    html += "<span>" + arr[i] + "</span>";
  }
  $(".this").closest(".string").html(html);
});
```

```css
.string span {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">Test1 Test2 Test3</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">TestA TestB TestC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to replace the div with 3 span or insert the span as children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to `.find` the `.string` inside the `.item` being iterated over with

```
var arr = $(this).find(".string").text().split(" ");
```

else your `$(".string")` will only match the first `.string` in the document. Then, to set the child `.string` of the `.item` being itearted over, use

```
$(this).find(".string").html(html);
```

(`closest` searches *ancestors*, not children)

Also make sure not to implicitly create a global variable with

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
```

(always declare variables you're going to use with `const`, `let`, or `var`)

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  var arr = $(this).find(".string").text().split(" ");
  var html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    html += "<span>" + arr[i] + "</span>";
  }
  $(this).find(".string").html(html);
});
```

```css
.string span {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">Test1 Test2 Test3</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">TestA TestB TestC</div>
</div>
```

Or, if possible, you might iterate over the `.string`s directly:

```js
$(".string").each(function() {
  var arr = $(this).text().split(" ");
  var html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    html += "<span>" + arr[i] + "</span>";
  }
  $(this).html(html);
});
```

```css
.string span {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">Test1 Test2 Test3</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">TestA TestB TestC</div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to use a regular expression `replace` - find non-space characters (`(\S+)`), and replace with those matched non-space characters surrounded by a `span`: `<span>$1</span>`:

```js
$(".string").each(function() {
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace(/(\S+)\s*/g, '<span>$1</span>')
  );
});
```

```css
.string span {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">Test1 Test2 Test3</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">TestA TestB TestC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have little bit mistake in your code.  change  `var arr = $(".string").text().split(" ");` to `var arr = $(this).find(">.string").text().split(" ");` to find the `.string` inside the `.item` which is in current iteration of loop.

And change  `$(".this").closest(".string").html(html);` to      `$(this).find(">.string").html(html);` to replace the html of `.string` inside the `.item` which is in current iteration of loop.

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  var arr = $(this).find(">.string").text().split(" ");
  var html = "";
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    html += "<span>" + arr[i] + "</span>";
  }
  $(this).find(">.string").html(html);
});
```

```css
.string span {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">Test1 Test2 Test3</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">TestA TestB TestC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all the `.string` elements and create a span for each text splitting by spaces.
Then replace the current `div` with the created spans:

```js
$.each($('.string'), (ind, val) => {
  const spans = $(val).text().split(' ').map(text => $(`<span>${text}</span>`));
  $(val).replaceWith(spans);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">Test1 Test2 Test3</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="string">TestA TestB TestC</div>
</div>
```